# Opening a website in batch file through its IP address

Tags: batch-file

I have a problem with my code.
I don't know how to open websites through ip in batch.
here is the code that I'm using:

```
@echo off
SET /A a = 0
title MNG ver.0.1
echo Initializing MNG ver.0.1
Timeout /t 5 /nobreak >nul
echo MNG initialized
Timeout /t 1 /nobreak >nul
echo which page do you want to visit?
Timeout /t 1 /nobreak >nul
echo 1.Newgrounds.com
Timeout /t 1 /nobreak >nul
echo 2.Youtube.com
Timeout /t 1 /nobreak >nul
echo 3.Facebook.com
Timeout /t 1 /nobreak >nul
echo 4.Exit
Timeout /t 3 /nobreak >nul
set /p answer=Select your choice
if "%answer%"=="1" (GOTO Label1)
if "%answer%"=="2" (GOTO Label2)
if "%answer%"=="3" (GOTO Label3)
if "%answer%"=="4" (GOTO Label4)

:Label1
start "chrome.exe" 51.79.77.158

:Label2
start "chrome.exe" 142.250.179.238

:Label3
start "chrome.exe" 157.240.214.35

:Label4
End
```

It has a lot of timeouts but they are to make the program look more hackery.
Like I was typing, this code can't turn on webpages through ip which is needed at my school, cause they have safeguards installed to prevent little children to play inappropriate game!(Friday night funkin on newgrounds to be exact)

Comment: You can use `start https://51.79.77.158` and Windows will figure out which app to launch, but unless your IT staff are morons, they'll be blocking by IP address, not by domain name.  Also note that you'll want to `goto :eof` after each start, otherwise it will flow into the next.

Comment: Also, you can write `if "%answer%" == "1" (start https://51.79.77.158)` directly.  You don't have to use goto.

Comment: There is also no guarantee that your proposed IPv4 addresses will resolve to the correct pages. There is a reason that there are DNS's.

Comment: Also, if the first argument to `START` is a quoted string, it will assume that it is intended as the TITLE of the resultant window; if you need to quote the name of the program you are starting, you'll have to use `START "" "C:\PATH WITH SPACES\EXEFILE.EXE"`. See [SS64 on `START`](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html).

Comment: Also also, if you do insist on using `goto` in this script or others, remember that batch files are executed on a line by line basis - therefor when you goto a label, everything after that label will be executed unless `exit /b` or `goto :eof` are scripted to end those labels. In your above script as it currently is written, a user selecting site `1` will result in all three sites being launched.

Comment: thanks to everyone who helped me with this program. I know everything that i needed so now no one needs to answer this question.